# Why do I see two rows rather than one?

Tags: html, css

In the code below (fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/tno3n3cq/), I expect to see a single row with two columns. Instead I see two rows.

I expect to see a single row because:

- the left side and right side elements are display: inline-block, so they should not be placed on their own line.
- the widths of the two sides add up to the width of the container, so they should both fit on one line.

Where is my reasoning wrong?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.filelist {
  width: 500px;
}

.bem-file {
  height: 37px;
}

.bem-left-side {
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}
    
.bem-right-side {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="filelist">
  <div class="bem-file">
    <div class="bem-left-side">
      left
    </div>
    <div class="bem-right-side">
      right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Comment: Because you have a parent div smaller (550px) then your columns (300px each)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, you're missing display: inline property for class filelist

```css
.filelist {
  width: 500px;
  display: inline;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bem-file {
    height: 37px;
}

.bem-left-side {
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bem-right-side {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.bem-file-name {
    display: inline;
}
.bem-upload-progress {

}

.alert-icon {
  color: red;
}

/* wuh? this is \e999 in the global icon demo. Did we get an old version? */
.alert-icon:before {
  content: "\e99b";
  color: #d37d7d;
}
```

```html
<div  class="filelist">
  <div  class="bem-file bem-file-error">
    <div  class="bem-left-side">
      <span  class="alert-icon"></span> 
      <div  class="bem-file-name">ripgrep-0.5.2-x86_64-apple-darwin.tar</div>
    </div>
    <div  class="bem-right-side">
      <span  class="status-message">File type invalid</span>
      <span  class="bem-upload-progress"></span>
      <span  aria-label="Remove" class="bem-remove-file bem-remove-file-error"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.filelist {
  width: 500px;
}


.bem-file {
    height: 37px;
    width: 100%;
    background : red;
    position:absolute;
}

.bem-left-side {
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    background:yellow;
}

.bem-right-side {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div  class="filelist">
  <div  class="bem-file">
    <div  class="bem-left-side">
      left
    </div>
    <div  class="bem-right-side">
      right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the block declaration from your CSS of both the bem-left and bem-right.